# changing the name of a gitlab installation

Tags: git, gitlab

I would like to change the welcome message on a local installation of gitlab.

Instead of "Welcome to Gitlab"
I would like to see: "Welcome to OurName"

where can I go to change that ?

Answer (score 0):

I do't see an obvious configuration in the [`gitlab-org/gitlab-foss` `config/gitlab.yml.example`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/06c127aa72cff78235426341081837cff0b6f78b/config/gitlab.yml.example) file.

And tests like [`qa/qa/specs/features/browser_ui/1_manage/project/dashboard_images_spec.rb`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/729eabcb410add9dbcfa46677308003dc95a64d0/qa/qa/specs/features/browser_ui/1_manage/project/dashboard_images_spec.rb#L30-36) seem to expect `'Welcome to GitLab'`

That being said, [`app/views/dashboard/projects/_zero_authorized_projects.html.haml`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/433ee53e3e473d6281fa70199c6e28dabc7846fd/app/views/dashboard/projects/_zero_authorized_projects.html.haml) seems to be using `welcome_title_content`.
Do check if this is a field in the associated  GitLab database.
If not, this could be a good feature request to add to the project.